# database url isn't being loaded from config file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, cloud9-ide

I have following `config` file

```
module.exports = {
    "database":"mongodb://<user>:<password>@xxDDDDDD.mlab.com:DDDDD/<user>",
    "secretKey":"YourSecretKey"
}
```

And here is where i am trying to read it and log

```
var express = require ('express');
var bodyParser = require ('body-parser');
var morgan = require ('morgan');
var config = require ('./config');
var mongoose = require ('mongoose');

var app = express();

mongoose.connect(config.database, function(err){
    if (err){
        console.log(config.database);
        console.log(config.secretKey);
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("Connedted to db");
    }
});
```

and here is my project structure

```
.
├── config.js
├── node_modules
│   ├── body-parser
│   ├── express
│   ├── mongoose
│   └── morgan
├── package.json
├── public
│   └── views
└── server.js
```

when i start server by issuing command `node server.js` i get the error `[Error: Invalid mongodb uri, Missing hostname]` which is because when i try to log `console.log(config.database)` it prints a blank line

Comment: I don't see any issue with the way you are loading it. I tried it and it prints correctly.

Comment: What happens when you try `mongoose.createConnection(config.database)` instead?

Comment: it throws error that `[Error: Invalid mongodb uri, Missing hostname]` since `hostname` is fetched as `empty`. The amazing thing is that `secretKey` is being properly fetched.